# Discord slash commands using python

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I have been looking at stackoverflow posts and so many places but still can't find the answer to this question that works for me. How do I make discord python slash commands?
Following this post :[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py#:~:text=import%20discord%20from%20discord.ext%20import%20commands%20create%20you,ids%20in%20which%20the%20slash%20command%20will%20appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py#:%7E:text=import%20discord%20from%20discord.ext%20import%20commands%20create%20you,ids%20in%20which%20the%20slash%20command%20will%20appear).
I got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/container/bot.py", line 3, in 
> bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="!")
> AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'

With this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@bot.slash_command(name="first_slash") #Add the guild ids in which the slash command will appear. If it should be in all, remove the argument, but note that it will take some time (up to an hour) to register the command if it's for all guilds.
async def first_slash(ctx): 
    await ctx.respond("You executed the slash command!")
```

I tried replacing "bot = discord.Bot" with "bot = commands.Bot" but that didn't work either

The only code I found had no errors was:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(bot)
@slash.slash(name="test")
async def _test(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.send("Hello World!")
```

But no slash commands appeared on discord

Comment: Neither of these snippets are discord.py. [Discord.py Interactions Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html)

Comment: Edit the tags to `pycord`, it's not `discord.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because you use discord's client and not discord.ext's.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=discord.Intents.all()) #gets all intents for the bot to work
```

Next up, slash won't be used (variable and event). Replace to this event:

```
@bot.hybrid_command(put same args as the actual code)
```

After this is done, update the Command Tree and it should appear no problem on Discord. Link here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#commandtree

Hope it helped. :D

EDIT: try this, It's your code but I modified it (if it works well for me, it will work well for you):

main.py:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=discord.Intents.all()) #intents are required depending on what you wanna do with your bot

@bot.hybrid_command(name="first_slash")
async def first_slash(ctx): 
   await ctx.send("You executed the slash command!") #respond no longer works, so i changed it to send

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   await bot.sync() #sync the command tree
   print("Bot is ready and online")

bot.run("Put your token here")
```

Now it should appear up to an hour after sync. Hope this helps more.
(Little precision: if you use Pycord, the code will be different)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I moved on to using nextcord.py though

Answer (score -3):

**OUTDATED**

Discord.py is no more updated.

If you want to use a more recent version of the discord module, you have to install pycord https://guide.pycord.dev/installation

To do this, first you have to uninstall the discord.py module using:
`pip uninstall discord.py`
And then install pycord using:
`pip install py-cord`

Your script will work like that:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Bot(debug_guilds=["YOUR TEST GUILD'S ID HERE"])

@bot.slash_command(name="first_slash")
async def first_slash(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("You executed the slash command!")
```

Comment: On March 5, 2022 Discord.py author Rapptz confirmed he has resumed development

https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6  
  
and added support for slash commands! (and it works beautifully)  
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/app_commands

Comment: @Deathhound Thanks for the examples! I spent the last 15 minutes searching all over the site and all the answers just were "switch to pycord" or outdated examples, smh