# how to make slash commands with reactions

Tags: python, discord.py

i would like to convert this code to support tree slash commands
here is the code
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, message):
await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
emb = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}",
description=f"asked by @{ctx.message.author}",
colour=random.choice(rcolor))
msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
await msg.add_reaction('')
await msg.add_reaction('')

```
@client.tree.command(name="poll", description = "case a vote to decide something")
async def poll(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    #i dont know what to put next
emb = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}",
                        description=f"asked by @{ctx.message.author}",
                        colour=random.choice(rcolor))
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
```

how can i do that?

my current command works but i would like to convert it to a slash command

Comment: you can look at this example, which could help you, https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py.

Comment: For further help could you please specify where your problem exactly is. Include error messages or a better description what is not working/the problem

Comment: there is no error message i just cant find a way to convert my command with reactions to a slash command

Comment: well what did you try? Did you try reading through the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=application%20command#application-commands)? Or have a look at other stack overflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)? Seems like you've done the barebones and just expect us to write the code for you which isn't the purpose of stack overflow.

Comment: have you synced your commands on start up? Because the code seems fine, without having it tested.