# How do I create slash commands in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot and it can respond to messages. But how do I make it have slash commands? I want to make a simple slash command that says something. How do I do that? Here is my code:
main.py:

```
import bot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run_discord_bot()
```

responses.py:

```
import random

swears = ["crap"] # i will add more later


def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    for x in range(len(swears)):   # loop for swears
        if p_message.__contains__(swears[x]) or p_message.__contains__("{swear}"):
            return "`PLEASE STOP SWEARING`"

    if p_message.__contains__("i will eat you"):
        return "no"

    return ""
```

bot.py:

```
import discord
import responses


async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private,):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        if response == "`PLEASE STOP SWEARING`":
            await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} {response}")    # sends to DM
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} {response}")   # sends to channel
        else:
            await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
        print(f"sent {response} to {message.author}")
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = "XXXX"
    bot = interactions.Client(TOKEN)
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f"{client.user} is up and running!")

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)
        if responses.get_response(user_message) == "":               # this makes the bot not respond to messages that are not swears
            return
        elif user_message[0] == "?":
            user_message = user_message[1]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

I tried using many ways like chatGPT, but the information was outdated. Ans I also tried this way:

```
import interactions
# somewhere in run_discord_bot:
    @bot.command(
        name="rules",
        description="shows the server rules",
    )
    async def rules(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
        await ctx.send("{rules}")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i make a working slash command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `~Interaction` from discord package.

*Same problem is found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)*

```py
from discord import Interaction

 # if slash command isn't in a cog
@client.tree.command(description="Shows the server rules") # removed the name param because it will raise an error as it is the same that the async function
async def rules(interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:

    rules = (
        "1. Don't say bad words",
        "2. Respect other people",
        "3. You mustn't speak loud in voice channels",
     )

    await interaction.response.send_message(f"{rules}")
```

In cogs

```py
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog);
    
    @app_commands.command(description="Shows the server rules")
    async def rules(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> None:
        ... # Here can be the same code that the slash command outside cog
```

You must know that `~Interaction.response` can only be sent once, then you must use `~Interaction.followup`.

Also, you must sync your commands, but I don't recommend you to sync them in the `on_ready` event, do something like this.

```py
from discord.ext.commands import is_owner, Context

@client.command()
@is_owner()
async def sync(ctx: Context) -> None:
    synced = await client.tree.sync()
    await ctx.reply("{} commands synced".format(len(synced)))
```

Comment: you mean insert your first piece of code into my bot.py run_discord_bot funcion and after the @client.event? (except from from discord import interactions)

Comment: @randomdude First code block is to create slash commands in the main file, second code blocks to create slash commands in cogs. All of these are like `@client.command()` decorator, where you have those, add the first code block.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I still don't really get it can you please make the edited files that have a basic slash command (main.py, responses.py, bot.py) into a github repository and send me the link back? I'm sorry but I don't get it. After this I will mark your answer correct. Again, I'm very sorry that I am wasting your time now but I'm really don't get it and it would be amazing if you helped me. THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: I will @randomdude