# Implementing a cooldown on a single slash command

Tags: discord.py

Is there any way to add a cooldown the following slash command?

```
from discord import *
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    commandamount = await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f"There are {len(commandamount)} commands")

@bot.tree.command(name="cooldown", description="Cooldown")
async def on_ready(interaction: Interaction):
    interaction.response.send_message("Hello")
```

I tried searching up tutorials, but there are either py-cord (a different library), or isn't a slash command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to implement cooldowns for discord.py

We can use the decorator: `@discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown(rate, per, *, key=...)` on our slash command to add a cooldown.

The `rate` is the:

> The number of times a command can be used before triggering a cooldown.

The `per` is the:

> The amount of seconds to wait for a cooldown when it’s been triggered.

### Example

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands  # to use in app commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)  # Create client
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)  # Set up application tree


@discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 3)  # add cooldown for every command three seconds of cooldown
@tree.command(name="cooldowntest", description="Test the cooldown", guild=discord.Object(
    id=yourguildid))
async def first_command(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Worked!")


@first_command.error  # Tell the user when they've got a cooldown
async def on_test_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await interaction.response.send_message(str(error),
                                                ephemeral=True)  # https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(guildidhere))  # sync tree
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Resources

- [Cooldown docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=checks%20cooldown#discord.app_commands.checks.cooldown)
- [Basic slash commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)