# Discord.py global slash command with configured input

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I make the code below look like this:

[Slash Prefilled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ci1.png)
[Slash PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq2Hk.png)

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def edit(ctx, user: discord.User, raid_type: str, change: str):
    if change not in ["+1", "-1"]:
        await ctx.send("Invalid input for change. Use +1 or -1.")
        return
    
    # Check if user exists in the database
    if not get_user(user.id):
        insert_or_update_user(user.id)

    user_data_before = get_user(user.id)
    if raid_type == "Thaemine":
        rank_before = user_data_before[2]
    elif raid_type == "Voldike":
        rank_before = user_data_before[4]
    elif raid_type == "Akkan":
        rank_before = user_data_before[6]
    elif raid_type == "Brelshaza":
        rank_before = user_data_before[8]
    elif raid_type == "Kayangel":
        rank_before = user_data_before[10]
    
    value = 1 if change == "+1" else -1
    update_raid_completion(user.id, raid_type, value)

    # Update rank before getting user data again
    user_data_after = get_user(user.id)
    if raid_type == "Thaemine":
        completion = user_data_after[1]
        update_rank(user.id, raid_type, completion)
        rank_after = get_user(user.id)[2]
    elif raid_type == "Voldike":
        completion = user_data_after[3]
        update_rank(user.id, raid_type, completion)
        rank_after = get_user(user.id)[4]
    elif raid_type == "Akkan":
        completion = user_data_after[5]
        update_rank(user.id, raid_type, completion)
        rank_after = get_user(user.id)[6]
    elif raid_type == "Brelshaza":
        completion = user_data_after[7]
        update_rank(user.id, raid_type, completion)
        rank_after = get_user(user.id)[8]
    elif raid_type == "Kayangel":
        completion = user_data_after[9]
        update_rank(user.id, raid_type, completion)
        rank_after = get_user(user.id)[10]

    # Send message only if rank has changed
    if rank_before != rank_after:
        general_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name="general")
        await general_channel.send(f'Congratulations {user.mention} on achieving the **{rank_after}** rank for {raid_type}! Completion Count: {completion}')

    # Send DM to user indicating what was edited
    if change == "+1":
        await user.send(f'Your {raid_type} completion count has been increased by 1. Your new count is: {completion} and your rank is: {rank_after}')
    else:
        await user.send(f'Your {raid_type} completion count has been decreased by 1. Your new count is: {completion} and your rank is: {rank_after}')
```

I'd like to stick to discord.py only and no forks. Thank you for the help in advance I appreciate it.
Been at this bot for many sleepless days and I'd finally would like to get this final part done to modernize it.

Answer (score 2):

Change bot.command to bot.hybrid_command and change ctx.send to ctx.respond (if you use ctx instead of interaction), I suggest reading the documentation https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=slash

or refer to this:
[How do i make a working slash command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)

please try to check if your answer could be answered in a similar question :)