# I am making a discord bot. i check when someone has posted a message whether that starts with gq.play to play the game. can someone use slash commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord game bot. i check when someone has psoted a message whether that starts with gq.play to play the game. can help me implement slash commands? i checked everywhere and didnt get anything about this.

This is my code:

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
import os
from threading import Thread
import keep_alive

class MyClient(discord.Client):

  async def on_ready(self):
    print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
    print('------')

  async def on_message(self, message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author.id == self.user.id:
      return

    if message.content.startswith('gq.play'):
      embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(54, 47, 217),title="Guess!",description="Guess a number between 1 and 10. \n You Have 5 Seconds!")
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

      def is_correct(m):
        return m.content.isdigit()

      answer = random.randint(1, 10)

      try:
        guess = await self.wait_for('message', check=is_correct, timeout=5.0)
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(233, 184, 36),title="⏰ Time's Up!",description=f"Times Up!, The answer was {answer}. Type gq.play to play again!")
        return await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

      if int(guess.content) == answer:
        embed=discord.Embed(discord.Color.from_rgb(122, 157, 84), title="✅ Correct!",description="Correct! Type gq.play to play again!")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
      else:
        embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(216, 0, 50),title="❌ Wrong!",description=f"Wrong!, the answer was {answer}. Type gq.play to play again!")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)

Thread(target=keep_alive.keep_alive).start()
client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

I tried using chatgpt but it is only using the old "discord_slash" package not the new one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i make a working slash command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)

Comment: nah, id oesnt help cause it works but it does show me error as i am awaiting for messages in between the game