# Disable certain commands for certain guilds with a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the slash commands to not show up for certain guilds. I cannot figure out how to do this. I am using hybrid commands so I would also want the text commands to not respond. I want a command only for guild owners that can toggle a certain command for a certain guild.

Comment: You would have to use the `@app_commands.guilds(123, 456, ...)` decorator to only allow the command showing up for these guilds.

Comment: @Dominik how would i fetch every guild id that it's in?

Comment: Create a list of all of the guild IDs you want to be able to use the slash-commands. Then set `guild_ids = list_of_servers`

Comment: @MacItaly thanks! also I use hybrid commands so how would i do that thing with it

Answer (score 0):

Documentation reference: [https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#decorators:~:text=%40discord.app_commands.guilds,it%20as%20a%20global%20command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#decorators:%7E:text=%40discord.app_commands.guilds,it%20as%20a%20global%20command).

I used this question/example as a base for my discord.py example:
[How do i make a working slash command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py)

I don't use discord.py, I use disnake.py for my bots. I've tried to assemble the best answer I can for you using what I've found in discord.py.

```
import discord
import discord.ext

intents = discord.Intents.all() 
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=Your guild ID here))
    # print "ready" in the console when the bot is ready to work
    print("ready")

# make the slash command (but it only works in guilds on the allowed_guilds list.
allowed_guilds = [111111111111111111, 222222222222222222, 333333333333333333]
@tree.command(name="name", description="description", guild_ids=allowed_guilds)
async def slash_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):    
    await interaction.response.send_message("command")

# run the bot
client.run("token")
```

Then you also have the ctx commands because you have a Hybrid bot. So something like...

```
@client.command
async def tester(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild.id in allowed_guilds:
        await ctx.send("Allowed guild")
    else:
        pass
```

Hope this helps! Happy coding!