# discord-py-slash-command package error message

Tags: discord.py

I installed discord-py-slash-command
this is the code i've used

```
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
```

the error message is

```
File "/home/runner/Index/main.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.py has supported slash commands for some time and is generally preferred nowadays over standalone implementations (at https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)

From there, I recommend using [How do i make a working slash command in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165431/how-do-i-make-a-working-slash-command-in-discord-py).